# Check if an item is in the list

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python. I am making a script that will check if an item  on the list is on a particular range, it will do some commands. and I have no idea how to make one. Im thinking of using an IF statement, but I think I'm wrong.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
list = [list of values]
if ( an entry on a list is lower than x): #given that x is any number
    do this
```

Comment: You want to check the entrys value? or index?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) on the list to return the smallest value. Thus:

```
if thelist and min(thelist) < x:
  print "There's something small in the list"
```

Comment: This unnecessarily traverses the entire list, and it raises `ValueError` when the list is empty.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Good points. I added a test for list validity. The performance penalty is of course true, but perhaps offset by `min()` being a built-in. I'll leave it, I think it has a clarity benefit at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(y < x for y in list):
    pass  # do something
```